# How to import data from excel to R as time series

Tags: r, excel, neural-network, time-series

I have this excel data sheet that I want to import into R as a time series object. However, i am not sure of how to go about it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSq8P.png)

how can i do that?
thanks.

Comment: The openxlsx packages has a read.xlsx function with a 'detect dates' flag.  We will need more specific issues in order to provide a better answer.

Comment: Please consider providing a reproducible question [reprex]